# Deleting duplicates based on another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am looking to delete duplicates in a column based on the contents of another column, and I can't seem to find an expression that works.

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Notice how the duplicates were removed in the second column (per project), based on the value of the first column?

For the life of me I don't even know what to google to solve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use [`Range.RemoveDuplicates`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one functionality in `excel` `remove duplicates`, Just you have to select your both column (which project and task ) and apply `remove duplicates`.

For Example :

- ### Duplicate column

[image]

- ### Apply From Data => remove duplicates

[image]

- ### Final result

[image]

Hope This Help!!!

Comment: It's easy and good one you get +10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest a two step solution.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell M29 :

  `=COUNTIF($K$29:L29,L29)`
- Now select K29:M49 and apply Filter command.
- Filter 1, 4 And 7 only.

[image]

- Now for neatness you may hide Column M.

[image]